# Highlight Words from a Regex Match

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to search a paragraph for certain text with `Regex`. I'd like the realist to return X number of words before and after and add highlights around all the occurrences of the text with.

**For Example**:
Consider the following paragraph. The result should have at least 10 characters before and after with no words cut off. The search term is "dog".

> The Dog is a pet animal. It is one of the most obedient animals. There
>   are many kinds of dogs in the world. Some of the are very friendly
>   while some of them a dangerous. Dogs are of different color like
>   black, red, white and brown. Some old them have slippery shiny skin
>   and some have rough skin. Dogs are carnivorous animals. They like
>   eating meat. They have four legs, two ears and a tail. Dogs are
>   trained to perform different tasks. They protect us from thieves b)
>   guarding our house. They are loving animals. A dog is called man's
>   best friend. They are used by the police to find hidden things. They
>   are one of the most useful animals in the world. Doggonit!

The result I desire is an array with that looks like the following:

- The **Dog** is a pet animal
- many kinds of **dog**s in the world
- dangerous. **Dog**s are of different
- rough skin. **Dog**s are carnivorous
- and a tail. **Dog**s are trained
- animals. A **dog** is called
- the world. **Dog**gonit!

**What I've Got:**

I've search around and have found the following regex that has perfectly returned the results as desired but without adding extra formatting. I created several methods to facilitate each functionality:

```
private List<List<string>> Search(string text, string searchTerm, bool searchEntireWord) {
    var result = new List<List<string>>();
    var searchTerms = searchTerm.Split(' ');
        foreach (var word in searchTerms) {
            var searchResults = ExtractParagraph(text, word, sizeOfResult, searchEntireWord);
            result.Add(searchResults);
            if (searchResults.Count > 0) {
                foreach (var searchResult in searchResults) {
                    Response.Write("<strong>Result:</strong> " + searchResult + "<br>");
                }
            }
        }
    return result;
}

private List<string> ExtractParagraph(string text, string searchTerm, sizeOfResult, bool searchEntireWord) {
    var result = new List<string>();
    searchTerm = searchEntireWord ? @"\b" + searchTerm + @"\b" : searchTerm;
    //var expression = @"((^.{0,30}|\w*.{30})\b" + searchTerm + @"\b(.{30}\w*|.{0,30}$))";
    var expression = @"((^.{0," + sizeOfResult + @"}|\w*.{" + sizeOfResult + @"})" + searchTerm + @"(.{" + sizeOfResult + @"}\w*|.{0," + sizeOfResult + @"}$))";
    var wordMatch = new Regex(expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

    foreach (Match m in wordMatch.Matches(text)) {
        result.Add(m.Value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And I can call it like:

```
var text = "The Dog is a pet animal. It is one of...";
var searchResults = Search(text, "dog", 10);
if (searchResults.Count > 0) {
    foreach (var searchResult in searchResults) {
        foreach (var result in searchResult) {
            Response.Write("<strong>Result:</strong> " + result + "<br>");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know yet the result of, or how to deal with, multiple occurrences of the word within the 10 characters. ie: if a sentence had "A dog is a dog of course!". I guess I can deal with that later.

**Tests:**

```
var searchResults = Search(text, "dog", 0, false); // should include only the matched word
var searchResults = Search(text, "dog", 1, false); // should include the matched word and only one word preceding and following the matched word (if any)
var searchResults = Search(text, "dog", 10, false); // should include the matched word and up to 10 characters (but not cutting off words in the middle) preceding and following it (if any)
var searchResults = Search(text, "dog", 50, false); // should include the matched word and up to 50 characters (but not cutting off words in the middle) preceding and following it (if any)
```

**Issues:**

The function I created allows the search to find the searchTerm as a whole word only or part of the word.

What I was doing was a simple `Replace(word, "<strong>" + word "</strong>")` on the results when displaying them. This works great if I was searching for parts of the word. But when searching for whole words, if the result included the searchTerm as part of the word, that part of the word would highlight.

**For example:** if I was searching for "dog" and the result was: "All dogs go to dog heaven." The highlighting would come out as "All **dog**s go to **dog** heaven." But I want "All dogs go to **dog** heaven."

**Question:**

The question is how can I get the *matched* word wrapped with some HTML like `<strong>` or anything else I'd want?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182747/discussion-on-question-by-rolyrolls-highlight-words-from-a-regex-match).

Comment: I think that your current description needs an update. You want to 1) extract all overlapping matches of your search words with surrounding texts, 2) wrap the words with terms in them / search terms as whole words (depending on the `searchEntireWord` option) with strong tags in each match. Right? If yes, you may try [this code](https://ideone.com/kUl456).

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew actually, I looked back at your previous solutions where I though it was not returning characters before the searched term if the previous word had a comma or a period. I did further tests and found that was not the case. I added my current solution in the chat. Would you mind reviewing and make any changes as needed.

Comment: I cleaned the pattern a bit and fixed the whole word `expression` pattern. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/HxLNZL). If it yields expected results, let me know, I will post an answer with explanation of each thing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does seem to work so far. Can you explain how your version of this segment `(?<!\w)(dog)(?!\w)` differs from mine `(\w*\b)(dog)(\b\w*)`?

Comment: `(?<!\w)(dog)(?!\w)` matches the whole word `dog`, and `(\w*\b)(dog)(\b\w*)` is practically the same, also matches a whole word `dog`. If you build the regex dynamically, and instead of `dog` there may be `[d]+o(g)`, you won't be able to use `\b`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew got it. One thing I just noticed, based on FurkanKambay is that this regex does not count contractions as a word, see [https://ideone.com/kfo69C](https://ideone.com/kfo69C) see the second result. The first character is an `s` which is part of the word `There's`

Comment: @RoLYroLLs `There's` are two words. Do you mean you consider `'` to be part of a "word" (a word in your definition)? Then you cannot use `\b` or `(?<!\w)`/`(?!\w)`. You need to define your "word" boundaries before moving further.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right that some contractions are considered as 2 words (like `I'm` `I'll` and `there's`) but in the context of returning such values, returning the letter `s` by itself for the word `there's` means nothing and therefore I'd rephrase to say: I'd like to return a word, contraction, or even hyphenated words, or even acronyms like N.A.T.O. (if ever written that way). Does that help? It looks like what I'm trying to say is "spaces" are what counts as a separation of word(s).

Comment: Then you need `(?<!\S)(dog)(?!\S)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183021/discussion-between-rolyrolls-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: @RoLYroLLs Try https://ideone.com/hPGS7N.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thats exactly what i ended up with =)

Comment: Cool, I'm at a concert now, I'll post an answer with all explanations once I'm back home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should be able to do two main things: 1) extract the matches, i.e. keywords/phrases plus additional left- and right-hand contexts round them, and 2) wrap the search terms with tags.

The extraction regex (for, say, 10 chars on the left and right) is

```
(?si)(?<!\S).{0,10}(?<!\S)\S*dog\S*(?!\S).{0,10}(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cAveTM/1).

**Details**

- `(?si)` - enable `Singleline` and `IgnoreCase` modifiers (`.` will match all chars and  the pattern will be case insensitive)
- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `.{0,10}` - 0 to 10 chars
- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `\S*dog\S*` - `dog` with any 0+ non-whitespace chars around it (*NOTE*: if `searchEntireWord` is *false*, you need to remove `\S*` from this pattern part)
- `(?!\S)` - a right-hand whitespace boundary
- `.{0,10}` - 0 to 10 chars
- `(?!\S)` - a right-hand whitespace boundary.

In C#, it will be defined as

```
var expression = string.Format(@"(?si)(?<!\S).{{0,{0}}}(?<!\S)\S*{1}\S*(?!\S).{{0,{0}}}(?!\S)", sizeOfResult, Regex.Escape(searchTerm)); 
if (searchEntireWord) { 
    expression = string.Format(@"(?si)(?<!\S).{{0,{0}}}(?<!\S){1}(?!\S).{{0,{0}}}(?!\S)", sizeOfResult, Regex.Escape(searchTerm)); 
}
```

Note that the `{{` is actually a literal `{` and `}}` is a literal `}` in the formatted string.

The second regex to wrap the key terms with strong tags is much simpler:

```
Regex.Replace(x.Value, 
            searchEntireWord ? 
                string.Format(@"(?i)(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)", Regex.Escape(searchTerm)) : 
                string.Format(@"(?i){0}", Regex.Escape(searchTerm)), 
            "<strong>$&</strong>")
```

Note that `$&` in the replacement pattern refers to the whole match value.

C# code:

```
public static List<string> ExtractTexts(string text, string searchTerm, int sizeOfResult, bool searchEntireWord) 
{
    var expression = string.Format(@"(?si)(?<!\S).{{0,{0}}}(?<!\S)\S*{1}\S*(?!\S).{{0,{0}}}(?!\S)", sizeOfResult, Regex.Escape(searchTerm)); 
    if (searchEntireWord) { 
        expression = string.Format(@"(?si)(?<!\S).{{0,{0}}}(?<!\S){1}(?!\S).{{0,{0}}}(?!\S)", sizeOfResult, Regex.Escape(searchTerm)); 
    } 
    return Regex.Matches(text, expression) 
        .Cast<Match>() 
        .Select(x => Regex.Replace(x.Value, 
            searchEntireWord ? 
                string.Format(@"(?i)(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)", Regex.Escape(searchTerm)) : 
                string.Format(@"(?i){0}", Regex.Escape(searchTerm)), 
            "<strong>$&</strong>"))
        .ToList();
}
```

[Sample usage (see demo)](https://ideone.com/hPGS7N):

```
var text = "The Dog is a real-pet animal. There's an undogging dog that only undogs non-dogs. It is one of the most obedient animals. There are many kinds of dogs in the world. Some of the are very friendly while some of them a dangerous. Dogs are of different color like black, red, white and brown. Some old them have slippery shiny skin and some have rough skin. Dogs are carnivorous animals. They like eating meat. They have four legs, two ears and a tail. Dogs are trained to perform different tasks. They protect us from thieves b) guarding our house. They are loving animals. A dog is called man's best friend. They are used by the police to find hidden things. They are one of the most useful animals in the world. Doggonit!";
var searchTerm = "dog";
var searchEntireWord = false;
Console.WriteLine("======= 10 ========");
var results = ExtractTexts(text, searchTerm, 10, searchEntireWord);
foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
======= 10 ========
(?si)(?<!\S).{0,10}(?<!\S)\S*dog\S*(?!\S).{0,10}(?!\S)
The <strong>Dog</strong> is a
an un<strong>dog</strong>ging <strong>dog</strong> that
only un<strong>dog</strong>s non-<strong>dog</strong>s.
kinds of <strong>dog</strong>s in the
<strong>Dog</strong>s are of
skin. <strong>Dog</strong>s are
a tail. <strong>Dog</strong>s are
A <strong>dog</strong> is called
world. <strong>Dog</strong>gonit!
```

Another example:

```
Console.WriteLine("======= 15 ========");
results = ExtractTexts(text, searchTerm, 15, searchEntireWord);
foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
======= 15 ========
(?si)(?<!\S).{0,15}(?<!\S)\S*dog\S*(?!\S).{0,15}(?!\S)
The <strong>Dog</strong> is a real-pet
There's an un<strong>dog</strong>ging <strong>dog</strong> that only
un<strong>dog</strong>s non-<strong>dog</strong>s. It is one of
many kinds of <strong>dog</strong>s in the world.
a dangerous. <strong>Dog</strong>s are of
rough skin. <strong>Dog</strong>s are
and a tail. <strong>Dog</strong>s are trained to
animals. A <strong>dog</strong> is called
in the world. <strong>Dog</strong>gonit!
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `Regex.Replace`:

```
public bool HighlightExactMatchOnly(string input, string textToHighlight, string expected)
{
    // given
    var escapedHighlight = Regex.Escape(textToHighlight);

    // when
    var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b" + escapedHighlight + @"\b", "<strong>$0</strong>");

    return expected == result;
}
```

Test:

```
var text = "My test dogs with a single dog and some text behind";
var expected = "My test dogs with a single <strong>dog</strong> and some text behind";
HighlightExactMatchOnly(text , "dog", expected);
```

Please note that this is not the fastest possible solution.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying this out, but unfortunately, we are still running C#5, can I'm trying to disect this to work in our solution. I'll get back to you if I get it, unless you can provide one sooner than I can figure it out. =)

Comment: So I figured it out (removing '$' and making sure the viables are correct. But I'm not getting the results. I'll be checking why.

Comment: But please be aware that https://ideone.com/R6iMNO provided by @Wiktor does much more than this example and might be the better solution. (here: only highlight, Wiktor's example extract excerpt AND highlight).